# Run-Timne error '1004': Highlighting range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will compare a previous expenditure report with the latest expenditure report.  The macro should pull data from the line in the Previous report and look for a Row that contains the exact same data, then highlight both Rows (in previous and latest report) to show that there was a match.  This will leave discrepancies un-highlighted in both the current and previous reports to be looked at to see if the discrepancies were intended (to be supported with documentation).

The code I have written is as follows:

```
Dim CPEAR As String
Dim PPEAR As String
Dim CL As Integer
Dim PL As Integer
Dim DL As Integer

Sub KDPM()
CPEAR = InputBox("Enter Current Pay Cycle (MM/DD/YYYY)", "Current Pay Cycle", , 50, 50)
CPEAR = CDate(CPEAR)
PPEAR = InputBox("Enter Previous Pay Cycle (MM/DD/YYYY)", "Previous Pay Cycle", , 50, 50)
PPEAR = CDate(PPEAR)


PL = 2

Do While Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Cells(PL, 2).Value = 1
    If Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Cells(PL, 6).Value = PPEAR Then
        CL = 2
        Do While Worksheets("CurrentPEAR").Cells(CL, 2).Value = 1
            If Worksheets("CurrentPEAR").Cells(CL, 2).Interior.ColorIndex <> 6 Then
                If Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Cells(PL, 3).Value = Worksheets("CurrentPEAR").Cells(CL, 3) Then
                    If Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Cells(PL, 4).Value = Worksheets("CurrentPEAR").Cells(CL, 4) Then
                        If Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Cells(PL, 7).Value = Worksheets("CurrentPEAR").Cells(CL, 7) Then
                            If Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Cells(PL, 12).Value = Worksheets("CurrentPEAR").Cells(CL, 12) Then
                                If Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Cells(PL, 14).Value = Worksheets("CurrentPEAR").Cells(CL, 14) Then
                                     Worksheets("CurrentPEAR").Range(Cells(CL, 1), Cells(CL, 21)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                                    Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Range(Cells(PL, 1), Cells(PL, 21)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                                    Exit Do
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        CL = CL + 1
        Loop



    End If
PL = PL + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

It seems to work fine through the first four rows of my data, but then it hits a runtime error.  Any Ideas?

And thanks for your help!

Comment: which line does throw the error?

Comment: You need to add the worksheet before **all** instances of `Cells()` - check the `.Interior.ColorIndex` lines for example, make sure to add the worksheet there.

Comment: [Flattening arrow code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) <~ please read

Answer (score 1):

As @BruceWayne mentions in the comments, you need to fully qualify all of your references to `Range`, `Cells`, and other global objects when you are building ranges:

```
Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Range(Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Cells(PL, 1), Worksheets("PreviousPEAR").Cells(PL, 21)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

This will get unwieldly with your already long code lines and multiple look-ups into the `Worksheets` collection, so grab references to your worksheets and/or put them in `With` blocks.  This helps performance tremendously:

```
With Worksheets("PreviousPEAR")
    .Range(.Cells(PL, 1), .Cells(PL, 21)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End With
```

Finally, you can use a `Select Case False` structure instead of deeply nested `If` statements if you want to short-circuit a bunch of expressions:

```
Select Case False
    Case Test1
    Case Test2
    Case Test3
    Case Test4
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "All conditions met"
End Select
```

That would make your loop look like the much more manageable...

```
With Worksheets("PreviousPEAR")
    Dim current As Worksheet
    Set current = Worksheets("CurrentPEAR")
    PL = 2
    Do While .Cells(PL, 2).Value = 1
        If .Cells(PL, 6).Value = PPEAR Then
            CL = 2
            Do While current.Cells(CL, 2).Value = 1
                Select Case False
                    Case current.Cells(CL, 2).Interior.ColorIndex <> 6
                    Case .Cells(PL, 3).Value = current.Cells(CL, 3)
                    Case .Cells(PL, 4).Value = current.Cells(CL, 4)
                    Case .Cells(PL, 7).Value = current.Cells(CL, 7)
                    Case .Cells(PL, 12).Value = current.Cells(CL, 12)
                    Case .Cells(PL, 14).Value = current.Cells(CL, 14)
                    Case Else
                        current.Range(current.Cells(CL, 1), current.Cells(CL, 21)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                        .Range(.Cells(PL, 1), .Cells(PL, 21)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                        Exit Do
                End Select
            CL = CL + 1
            Loop
        End If
    PL = PL + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: shouldn't all those `=` in `Select Case` block be `<>` ?

Comment: @user3598756 - Nope. It's selecting the `False` case, so it will only propogate through the cases if they are `True`.

Comment: @Cominter,  You are the most amazing person I have ever met.  I used your example and tweaked and it works flawlessly!  Thank you and BruceWayne so much for the help.  You Guys Rock!